# Is there any app for stackexchange?

Tags: feature-request

Id like to use stackexchange from any app available in the market,the browser kills me when searching sites.

Comment: This question probably belongs in meta. And as far as I know, there are some "viewers" on the store but not a definitive kind of apps which can help you in editing the posts or anything. It's not there even on iOS or Android yet.

Answer (score 3):

An official Android version has recently been released http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/stack-exchange-for-android-is-here/. An iOS version is in the works, but unfortunately no word on a Windows Phone version.

Comment: In the comments of the thread where they announce the new [API V2.2](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/02/stack-exchange-api-v2-2-and-the-demise-of-v1-x/) they made somewhat clear that they don't have plans right now to do an WP app and the API provide the ways to someone else to do. :'(

Comment: I downloaded the iOS app yesterday. Works a treat! :-)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is **Yes**. And [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/stack-mate/9nblggh0jf49) is one you can use. Not officially created nor has a title of **StackExchange** but it does possesses all the features you'll need. I'm using it and very happy with that. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Yup there is! But the thing is its a WebApp.

You can get from here. http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/store/app/webapps/49e97b4c-7715-4103-8519-066244fc9e2f?signin=true

Comment: You might want to elaborate a little more about what `WebApp` does and the pros/cons.

Comment: It also appears to be only on the India store

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an official one so NO is the answer. But one or 2 people have wrapped the mobile web app and published but this is same as visiting stack overflow on you mobile browser.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is a WP [meta] site, but there is now a SE iOS app. Yesterday, on a whim, I had the same question, as the OP, myself and searched the AppStore. To my surprise I found one. I downloaded it, and it is very good.

Highly Recommended.

Answer (score 1):

There is one app, still not an official app, but it has a very good user interface, designed using the Windows 10 design language. Its called [Stackie](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/stackie/9nblggh6gzv5)

[image]

[image]

All StackExchange sites are available. Scroll down the `Pin a Site` modal to reveal and pin your favorite Stack Sites.

Comment: The app is not limited. Other sites appear once you scroll down the list. Yes, it is a Windows 10 UWP app.Thanks for pointing it out. It works great for me.

Comment: Okay, I hadn't found that out. Let me check it out and edit my comment. Thanx